# Global load balancing - mesosphere

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere, dcos

We are having a Mesosphere DCOS environment where we have different pools/clusters based on regions. How can I setup global load balancing so that I have traffic balanced between pools/clusters. Basically, I am looking to make my deployment highly available by deploying the components to multiple pools.

How can I achieve this in Mesosphere?

Environment:

- DCOS
- Marathon
- Docker
- RHEL
- HAProxy

Comment: Is that one cluster spanning multiple regions?

Comment: I am using the terms cluster and pool interchangeably. Our pools are similar to AWS availability zones. e.g. we may have two pools in EMEA (EMEA-1 & EMEA-2) and Three pools in NA (NA-1, NA-2, NA-3).

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of your infrastructure? It will be easier to understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

DC/OS 1.11 supports [availability zones](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/oss/high-availability/). First of all make sure you understand the terminology and what is exactly is your setup:

- **zone** an isolated data center (there should be low latencies between two zones within the same region)
- **region** a geographical region e.g.`us-west`(you can have each data center on a different continent) - this setup is [currently not supported](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/oss/high-availability/multi-region/).

So, a **multi-zone** setup is possible. For **multi-region** you'd need independent DC/OS clusters, because latencies between regions might be too high.